# SOAP API for Java filter and sort Orders by order id

Tags: orders, api, filter, soap

I am using **Magja**, java soap api for magento. I want to filter orders by order id or any other property, also want to sort orders by ASC or DESC. But my current code is not working for that, I need help to sort this out, thanks in advance for any help. My current code for filter is below

```
TestOrder to = new TestOrder();
OrderFilter filter = new OrderFilter();
filter.getItems().add(new OrderFilterItem("state", "=", "new"));
filter.getItems().add(new OrderFilterItem("store_id", "=", "3"));
filter.getItems().add(new OrderFilterItem("order_id", "gt","300000065"));       
List<Order> list = to.service.list(filter);
```

**Note:** filters by state and store_id are working fine. But order_id/increment_id filters(gt, lt, eq etc) are not working at all.

Answer (score 1):

First of all calling this is wrong.

```
filter.getItems().add(new OrderFilterItem("order_id", "gt","300000065"));
```

`order_id` does not exist. it is `entity_id`. And the value `300000065` looks like an `increment_id` value, not a table PK id.

This should work (I have no idea if you should use `gt` or `>` try them both).

```
filter.getItems().add(new OrderFilterItem("order_id", "gt","12"));
```

As for filtering by the `increment_id` maybe you should take into account that the field is not numerical. it is `varchar(50)`. Maybe this affects your filtering.